# Compiling C++ code for R (CRAN) packages on Solaris

Tags: r, makefile, gnu-make, solaris, cran

I am a little bit confused on how to efficiently prepare the R package, so that it will be compatible across all needed system platforms. This is needed so that the new version of package will be accepted by CRAN. The main difficulty comes from compiling external C++ shared library, and optionally CUDA version if the compiler is available. To support this flow I've created specific Makefile, unfortunately using GNU-extensions. It works fine on Linux, OSX and when executed manually via `gmake` on Solaris. Relevant part is here:

```
# Checking whether nvcc compiler is available
NVCC_TEST = $(shell basename $(shell which nvcc 2> /dev/null)"")

ifeq ($(NVCC_TEST),nvcc)
    ALL_LIBS += libcucubes_gpu.so
    ALL_OBJS += $(GPU_OBJS)
    ALL_FLAGS += $(GPU_FLAGS)
else
    ALL_OBJS += gpu_fallback.o
endif
```

Turns out that, when running `R CMD INSTALL (...)` on Solaris, the installation fails on something like this:

```
make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 39: Unexpected end of line seen
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'libcucubes'
```

As it turns out, it is caused by the fact that Solaris' version of `make` is executed instead of GNU-compatible `gmake` (I've tested it works fine), even though it is available. My question is whether there is any simple way to force usage of `gmake` here, for the R package build. In general I know I could use `autotools` to solve compatibility issues during installation, but it seems to bring too much complexity for that simple case. Any advices will be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could use `CMake` to create `Makefile`.

Comment: The best solution so far is to create `Makefile` per environment and a handwritten `./configure` (`./bin/sh` compliant) script to switch them depending on the operating system and availability of CUDA modules...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get your build process to use `gmake` instead of Solaris's pure POSIX `make`, you can use this hack:

1. Make a dedicated directory for this hack:  `mkdir $HOME/make_hack`
2. Softlink `gmake as`make`in that directory:  ln -s /path/to/gmake $HOME/make_hack/make`
3. Set your PATH:  `PATH=$HOME/make_hack:$PATH`

Now, run your build process using that `PATH`, and it should use `gmake`.  Hopefully it just uses `make` from its `PATH` envval and not some hardcoded full path.

Yeah, it's a hack.  But it's probably a lot easier than modifying the build process to use `gmake` instead of `make`.

Comment: The problem is that the solution ought to work by default, as the package is intended to be widely available via CRAN.

Comment: @TomekFalkiewicz *The problem is that the solution ought to work by default* True, but [I also want a pony.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/70650)  ;-)

Comment: Please read a bit more carefully, cause it's not the matter of pony. For some reason your solution is answering the question on how to override `PATH` in *nix systems, which I didn't ask, while totally negating the CRAN requirement which is the main point of the problem. However the brute force solution is simple: switch multiple Makefiles using custom `./configure` script.

Comment: @TomekFalkiewicz If you know how to get your compile to work, why are you asking then?

Comment: Opting out from this conversation, cause either you keep trolling me, still didn't get time to read through the question or cannot comprehend meaning of words like _efficiently_ or _brute force solution_. Good luck with your reputation points hunt!

Answer (score 1):

From [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Writing-portable-packages):

> If you really must require GNU make, declare it in the DESCRIPTION
>   file by
>
> ```
> SystemRequirements: GNU make
> ```
>
> and ensure that you use the value of environment variable MAKE (and
>   not just make) in your scripts.

`configure` scripts are the preferred solution though. BTW, in general a `Makevars` file is also preferred over a full `Makefile`.